# Is the phrase "I wish you a good mood" used by native English-speakers?

Tags: phrases

Strict search yields many hits but the authors all seem to be foreigners. Thanks.

Comment: I have never heard that. If it is used, I'd expect it to be in the context of drug use. (Medical as well as recreational.) Far more common would be *please have a good time* or *I wish you well*, but it's not possible to say exactly, because it's not clear what is actually trying to be expressed.

Comment: It's like a wish for a birthday, when a speaker wishes a person to always stay in high spirits (cheerful, optimistic).

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard the phrase "I wish you a good mood." In your comment you clarify your meaning:

> It's like a wish for a birthday, when a speaker wishes a person to
>   always stay in high spirits (cheerful, optimistic).

The normal birthday wish or greeting is "I wish you a happy birthday" or "Happy Birthday, shiko!" In my part of the English-speaking world, we insert whatever day it is, e.g. Easter, Canada Day, New Years Day or sometimes just Thursday or rest of the day. These are often used instead of, or part of, saying good-bye.

Another one is "Enjoy the rest of your day," or "I hope you have a good time with your family tonight/on your trip [or whatever they said they were going to do]."

If conversation had been somewhat heavy about problems, one might say, "Keep your chin up" (meaning "Keep your mood up, remain optimistic.") or "Don't let it get you down," (meaning "Don't become depressed or give up just because things are tough or because it looks hopeless.")

A very common phrase is "I wish you all the best."

There must be more but I can't think of any that say exactly what you are asking for. We wish each other well and we want people to be happy and in a good mood, but we might have a different way of getting the message across than your native language and culture does. Languages and cultures differ that way but underneath humans pretty much all want the same things--they just find different ways of expressing themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer)